# Instagram's Post Comment Button Wont Work? Selenium In Python

Tags: python, selenium, post, button, instagram

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

user = 'username'
passw = 'password'



driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(user)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(passw)
Login = "//button[@type='submit']"
sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(Login).submit()
sleep(1)
# Logs into Instagram
print ('Logged In')

#------------------------ATTENTION

NotNow = "//button[contains(text(),'Not Now')]"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(NotNow).click()
# Clicks Pop Up
print ('Close Pop Up')

# It's weird but the pop up opens once, only after this page.
# If ever a problem delete one, or have the first click be
# directed to your Instagram Profiles timeline

NotNow = "//button[contains(text(),'Not Now')]"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(NotNow).click()
#Clicks Pop Up
print ('Close Pop Up')

#-----------------------------------



driver.refresh()
print ('refreshing')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


LeaveComment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/form[*[local-name()='textarea']]")
LeaveComment.click()

LeaveComment2 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('textarea')
LeaveComment2.send_keys("look at this @programmer.chad nice post!")

#Xpath of the Post button on Instagram
Post = "//div/form/[*[local-name()='button']/@type='submit']"

#Xpath of the Form where the Post button is located
Form = "//div[*[local-name()='form']]"

#LeaveComment2.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#ERROR IS BELOW
driver.find_element_by_xpath(Post).submit()
```

This code logins into an Instagram account leaves a comment under the first post on your timeline and posts it. but I'm unable to Post a comment tagging my other account. Any other comment works fine using .send_keys(Keys.Enter). So I attempted to use .click() and use .submit() on the `XPath` of the button where "Post" is located but it doesn't post. Sometimes it won't even send an error message.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the Xpath of the Post button to:

```
Post = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div/div[2]/div/article[1]/div/div[3]/section[3]/div/form/button'
```

And change this function `driver.find_element_by_xpath(Post).submit()`
to this one `driver.find_element_by_xpath(Post).click()`

Comment: kinda mad that actually worked..... lmao thank you. The section[3] sometimes becomes section[2] on Instagram so I may have to prepare for that. Appreciate this tho